# Stymied building this cross-database query

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-update

I'm trying to migrate some data from an old database to a new one with a slightly different schema and my SQL isn't terribly strong.

Old schema:  There is a table we'll call "Person" with a field which can have set of permutations of 3 flags.  The Person table has a foreign key to another table we'll call "Flags".  They Flags table has rows for each of these flag combinations in a String:

```
1 - Yes No No
2 - Yes Yes No
3 - Yes No Yes
4 - Yes Yes Yes
5 - No Yes No
6 - No Yes Yes
7 - No No Yes
```

The new schema doesn't require this table (thankfully).  These flags are simply fields in the "Person" table now as BIT fields.

What I want to do is something like a:

```
UPDATE database2.Person SET (flag1, flag2, flag3) VALUES (true, false false) WHERE database1.Person.flag_id = 1;
```

I could then run 7 different queries changing the IDs and the values accordingly.  The problem, of course, is that the above isn't correct SQL.  I think I need some kind of JOIN ...or a subselect in the where clause or something?

Stumped on the best way forward.  My parting thought here is that this doesn't need to be compressed into a single query, or particularly elegant.  I expect to run this query once and be done with it.

Comment: Bet you'd like to hurt who ever came up with that. @paul solution pretty much mirrors waht I was thinking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
update database2.Person p2 join database1.Person p1 on p1.PersonId = p2.PersonId
set    flag1 = case when p1.Flag_id in (1,2,3,4) then true else false end case,
       flag2 = case when p1.Flag_id in (2,4,5,6) then true else false end case,
       flag3 = case when p1.Flag_id in (3,4,6,7) then true else false end case
```

(edited for mySQl syntax)

Comment: Yep this worked like a charm.  I didn't think to use case statements in the set.  Perfect.

Answer (score 0):

This should work if I'm understanding your question.  It assumes you have a `Person_Id` matching in each table.

```
UPDATE db2.Person p
    JOIN db1.Person p2 ON p.Person_Id = p2.Person_Id
SET p.Flag1 = 1, 
    p.Flag2 = 0, 
    p.Flag3 = 0
WHERE p2.Flag_Id = 1;
```

---

If the flag values in the Flags table were columns, you could easily run a single query, but as I'm understanding it, it's just a string field.  This is an example:

```
UPDATE db2.Person p
    JOIN db1.Person p2 ON p.Person_Id = p2.Person_Id
    JOIN db1.Flags f ON p2.Flag_Id = f.Flag_Id
SET p.Flag1 = CASE WHEN f.Flag1 = 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
    p.Flag2 = CASE WHEN f.Flag2 = 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
    p.Flag3 = CASE WHEN f.Flag3 = 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```